# Rest api and c# driver for cassandra other than datastax

Tags: rest, cassandra

I am newbie to `Cassandra` and was exploring to start the `Cassandra` as a `Rest server` so that i can perform the `CRUD operations` irrespective of language. I always find the DataStax solution for above problems. Isn't there any in-built functionality for Rest server in `Cassandra` like stargate in `HBase`?

Comment: What's wrong with the DataStax solutions?

Comment: Simple, I don't want to pay for it. That is the reason i am searching for some open source solution.

Comment: Ok, so I did a search and there are very few Datastax solutions. Probably because afaik DataStax don't have a rest api solution. Try https://code.google.com/p/restish/

Answer (score 0):

Old question but just in case someone else stumbles across this there's, coincidentally, another Stargate project you can use, https://stargate.io/. The project is an open source data gateway that sits in front of (well, technically you could say within since it runs as a coordinator node) your Cassandra cluster exposing REST, Graphql, and a Documents API. As of now it supports Cassandra 3.11, Cassandra 4.0, and DSE 6.8.